# lmertest and confidence intervals

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval, lmertest

Is there a way to get lmertest to produce confidence intervals?

I have tried using this code from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/lmerTest.pdf

```
contest(mymodel , L, rhs = 0, joint = TRUE,
        collect = TRUE, confint = TRUE, level = 0.95,
        check_estimability = FALSE, ddf = c("Satterthwaite", "Kenward-Roger",
                                            "lme4"), ...)
```

But I get this error

```
Error in contest(mymodel, L, rhs = 0, joint = TRUE, collect = TRUE, confint = 
TRUE,  : 
  could not find function "contest"
```

Comment: Have you installed the package and successfully loaded the library with `library(lmerTest)`?

Comment: yes. I am able to compute the model with the command lmer and review the summary.

Comment: `lmerTest` is a separate library from `lme4` though, you have to install and load it separately.

Comment: yes I have installed lmertest     library(lmerTest)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why I received errors using the contest function above. I reloaded the package and re-ran my script but still got this error:

```
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
```

However, there is a simple solution to obtain the confidence intervals within the lme4 package:

```
CI <- confint (mymodel)
```